Why doesn't liberal California just implement Universal Healthcare on its own?
California has an overwhelming left-leaning majority that probably loves the idea of universal healthcare. But even if you don't want to take the whole of California (which still has a large conservative presence in its rural areas), you could focus on select counties or cities like SF, which are undeniably overwhelmingly progressive.
Why don't they implement Universal Healthcare on their own (since getting the entire nation to go with it seems impossible). They have a progressive supermajority that I'd imagine wants it, as well as an absurdly high GDP to support it. So what's stopping them from doing it? And conversely, it seems to me that if even California won't go for it, then the mere hope that the entire nation would go for it seems absurd.
The only explanations I can think of is that I incorrectly assumed liberal Californians overwhelmingly want Universal Healthcare, or that those running California are in the pocket of insurance companies and special interests (and so refuse to make it happen). Or maybe I'm just underestimating the practicality of a single state/district having Universal Healthcare on its own?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Because there is a strong possibility that anyone who ever had a health risk would migrate to California and bankrupt the system.  Meanwhile, given the extra taxes needed to pay for it, anyone feeling healthy would move out.
The reason even Obamacare doesn't work very well is because countries that have successfully implemented universal health care have taken away the rights of individuals to opt out.  Most of us, in countries running those programs, understand that we get less out of the system than we put in.  Until we need it  (which, btw, is precisely the very notion of an insurance model).
Meanwhile, a side gain is also to limit the massive paperwork needed to manage enrollment ("ugh, keep the sicks out!") and claims in the US.  In the California hypothesis, that paperwork would be replaced by lawsuits and/or administrative challenges whenever California tried to ration care for recent arrivals.
It's simple economics - and common sense - that make universal health care work * (though not necessarily in poor or corrupt countries).  Not politics.  That's why even right wing studs like Boris Johnson or Orban still run these programs.
* within limits:  ageing populations stress these programs, massively.  But, in the US, thanks to gray power, Medicare still stresses taxpayers.  To the tune of $829B in 2021.
p.s. Simple economics is based on the US spending more per capita than other countries.  For comparatively bad outcomes.  I would expect tax-watchful, but politically  neutral, individuals to be able to work through the implications of this math.
Rest fully assured:  any health care providers that are part of that gravy train can be expected to strenuously object to rationalization that would bring costs in line with the USA's peers and near-peers.
p.p.s.  No, provincial/regional management of plans in some countries doesn't change the fact that the availability of health care is present nationally and the funding often carries a sizable central component.
Update, from comments:  There was no federal medical system when Tommy Douglas introduced the Saskatchewan Hospitalization Act in 1947. This was not a universal system, but I think it was close enough to counteract the "people would just move there for medical care" argument..  Possibly, but I would still worry, a lot, if I were doing this in 2024, in California, at current healthcare costs and procedures, much higher population mobility, with the current CA deficit and with an aging population.
p.p.p.s.  "But the poor get covered through Medicaid!" misses the point that its coverage can be sub-par when compared to the more egalitarian European or Canadian universal plans.  And tying coverage to employers can be economically bad both by keeping workers in suboptimal jobs and the financial burden to employers.
All these undesirable characteristics remain with a California homebrew.  Which, as another answer points out, would only be improving things for 6.5% of hitherto-uncovered people, at very significant costs, making rejection whenever such bills are proposed unsurprising.
Let's finish up with why this bill failed the last time it was presented:
(Feb 2022) California Democrats Kill CalCare, a Single-Payer Health Care Proposal | The New Republic

CalCare was murdered like Caesar: betrayed by its ostensible allies, all of whom participated so that none of them could be fully blamed.


Why the betrayal? Because the bill was a nonstarter for California’s most powerful business groups. The California Chamber of Commerce led a coalition of 122 business groups in opposition to the bill. Opposition was the most vehement from the groups representing Big Health Care

This is the pro-bill side, complaining.  Is it incompatible with the analysis above?  Not really:  the current providers would have much to lose if moving to a less wasteful model, comparable with other countries.
And their own link pointing to those dastardly Brutuses:
(Jan 2022) Calif. Chamber of Commerce Announces 122-Member Coalition Opposed to Single Payer Health Care Proposals

In their letter, the coalition points out that similar past proposals have been estimated to cost more than $400 billion annually, which is a financial commitment four times that of Medi-Cal. "Successfully standing up a new function that would be twice the size of the existing state budget is highly doubtful, given the state's recent experience with benefit delays and massive fraud in the unemployment system," the letter states.

More recently...
(Jan 2024 this time) California single-payer healthcare faces doubts from Democratic leader - Los Angeles Times

A legislative analysis of that bill (note: the 2022 version) pegged the cost between $314 billion and $391 billion in state and federal funds — a sum that is larger than the entire state budget Gov. Gavin Newsom proposed for the 2024-25 fiscal year: $291.5 billion.


The proposals usually wind up dividing Democrats and withering due to concerns over cost, opposition from private insurers and the complex bureaucracy that undergirds the nation’s delivery of healthcare.

And since numbers matter with budgets, let's work through this math.

314$B   cost, lower estimate
39M pop * 0.065 : currently wo coverage
$123k / person => how much it would cost to implement this plan

in the interest of transparency:  how is that estimate costed?  Per year?  For the first 5 or 10 years (as sometimes done with budget projections)?  Permanently, with an endowment fund to pay for it?  123k/yr/person seems absurdly high.  None of articles I saw were all that clear.

In the California hypothesis, that paperwork would be replaced by lawsuits and/or administrative challenges whenever California tried to ration care for recent arrivals. See, Saenz v. Roe, 526 U.S. 489 (1999) for a similar case of rationing that the Supreme Court overturned.

“Because anyone who ever had a health risk would migrate to California and bankrupt the system. Meanwhile, given the extra taxes needed levied to pay for it, anyone feeling healthy would move out.” It sounds like you are making a forecast, but you are phrasing it in a way that makes it sound certain. I think we need a logically rigorous argument for what the probability of this outcome is and why. Otherwise, I think it is an unsubstantiated claim, and the answer would be improved by removing those parts.

As I understand it, the OP’s question is about why California has not attempted to implement universal income on the state level, given the assumption that a majority of Californian people would want it. This answer seems to me to be about why universal healthcare would not work in California, which is a different topic. The answer could be revised to explain why Californians have not successfully implemented universal health care.

First point, 'Liberal California' is more of a Rightist meme than a practical reality. Yes, California has distinct and vocal left-leaning groups; Yes, California is a strongly Democrat state; Yes, California has a lot of movie stars who tend to be liberal and outspoken. But the movie industry itself is Big Money and anything but liberal, agriculture and the military are two of its largest industries, and Silicon Valley is all about adventure capitalism. California produced (and elected) Ronald Reagan, Devin Nunes, and Clint Eastwood, and our current Governor (often tarred with the Liberal brush) is really an oligarchical centrist. California is considered 'liberal' because it's a rich state that's willing to spend its money on citizens, and unwilling to pander to theocrats and oppressive xenophobes. Best not to exaggerate its 'lefty-ness'…
Second, Universal Health Care needs to be handled on the federal level. Trying to implement it on the state level would produce a host of problems involving legislation of trans-state industries like insurance companies and major medical providers, e.g.:

federal interstate commerce lawsuits
loss of services and revenue as industries pull out of the state
a largish increase in state taxes
a deterioration of already already impacted housing markets (not to mention homelessness) as under-insured people from other states move to California for medical care

Californians respect the ideal that California should lead the country by passing universal health care, I suppose, but despite appearances California is not all that idealistic a state. Remember, it was not the first state to allow gay marriage or to legalize marijuana. We shouldn't reasonably expect it to take the lead here, either.

“'Liberal California' is more of a Rightist meme than a practical reality.” I think this is an unsubstantiated claim. The answer can be improved by removing this part or rewording it to express a verifiable assertion and then providing a means of verification. Thank you.

Legalization of same-sex marriage isn't a great issue for measuring social attitudes because in most states, it was done by the judiciary instead of by the voters.  FWIW, the first legislation to allow it was in Vermont in 2009 (but they had "civil unions" since 2000).

@JuliusHamilton: That claim is precisely what the paragraph substantiates. I mean, 'Liberal California' is indisputably a phrase used heavily by the political Right, and the rest is examples of why that phrase doesn't quite apply.  I'm not sure what you;'re objecting to, really…

Medicaid and Medicare already cover the most vulnerable groups
Back in 1965 when Medicaid and Medicare were first introduced, one could make a compelling argument for how the government needs to support the elderly and the poor. As of 2024 this argument doesn't work as well, since those two groups are already covered.
Only 6.5% of California residents are uninsured
As per the America's Health Rating website, only 6.5% of California residents don't have insurance. Most people either have a corporate healthcare plan, are retired and have Medicare or are poor and have Medicaid. Therefore 93.5% of California voters have little incentive to vote for a Universal Healthcare plan. And they're unlikely to be overly sympathetic towards a person who makes (say) $100k/year but chooses to not buy an insurance plan. Some of those not covered are foreign nationals who usually get even less sympathy from voters when it comes to use of public funds.
Most Americans like their insurance
From Forbes:

A 2022 Forbes Advisor survey found that 85% of Americans said they are at least somewhat happy with their health insurance plans

I don't have the stats for California specifically but I imagine they should be similar.
Well off Americans would be worse off with Universal Healthcare
If you have a good job with a solid insurance plan and live in a major city, you've got incredible access to medical services of any kind. Low wait times, doctors who smile and listen (you're a customer, so they have to!), large choice of providers, low out-of-pocket costs. Most of these perks will go away if Universal Healthcare is implemented, so there's a strong incentive to vote against it.
So... who's going to vote for this plan? The 6.5% who don't have insurance for whatever reason? That's 43.5% too little, so this won't happen any time soon.

Possibly related to "who's going to vote for this plain": Does the 93.5%/6.5% split include only citizens or also people who are in the US but not citizens - some of who are legally are here, some of whom are illegally here but none of whom can vote. If the 6.5% includes a higher ratio of non-citizens than the 93.5% then that makes it even harder to get a bill passed to help them.

That doesn't explain why for example Medicaid exists in the first place. After all, who would vote for that? People did. One could just expand Medicaid to cover also the missing 6.5% if people wanted that, or not?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution status quo bias wins by default. Lots of things could be passed, doesn't mean they will be passed.

Sure, but the same argument you bring for the 6.5% being 43.5% too little also counts for Medicaid but still Medicaid was introduced in 1965 and expanded in 2010. Significantly more people must have voted for that than profited from it. Maybe the same could happen here and your estimation in the last paragraph is oversimplifying things and could be wrong.

Are well-off Americans still as well-off once they develop some serious issues and have incurred hefty bills?  What will that look like if they have to switch providers or employers?  Plus, I believe directly purchased insurance (i.e. not your employer) are quite expensive even if you are healthy?  $2100/mo for 57 and 53 yo adults and 2 adult children if ineligible for low cost state plans sound right?

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica well off Americans have a plan with a yearly cap of $2-3k/year in out of pocket expenses. At the very worst you have a $5k/year cap for “out of network” expenses. You simply cannot go broke from non-cosmetic medical care as long as you’re insured. And yes, costs can be high for a bit if you lose your job but Medicaid will kick in after a year if you have no income. You can also buy insurance against disability to cover yourself against extreme outcomes.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica switching providers is not a problem at all, unless you live in a small city where there aren’t enough doctors. Switching employers is not a problem either, you can get a reasonably priced COBRA plan for up to 18 months to cover you in between jobs.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Medicaid is a Federal program. Nobody "voted for it". They voted for enough lawmakers in three separate bodies who supported for it. There's a significant political difference. On the other hand, particularly in California with its history of ballot propositions, citizens would regularly be able to vote it up or down directly.

California could adopt a universal health care system.
It would need some cooperation with the federal government to do it, because every U.S. state has many people who get their healthcare through the federal Medicare program and Veteran's Administration health care system, because California has contractual obligations related to its participation in the joint state-federal Medicaid program and several smaller federal health care programs, because it would have to figure out how its Obamacare non-employer health insurance marketplace would be dealt with, and because it would have to do so in a manner that is sensitive to the federal tax code which includes Obamacare tax credits (and Obamacare investment taxes) and various exclusions from income.
Still, these are not insurmountable barriers. Every state has its own state level worker's compensation program with is (in part) a form of universal healthcare system for work related injuries and illnesses. A number of states have "no fault" car insurance which is effectively a universal health care program for minor injuries from car accidents. Every state has a system of health care for its prison and jail inmates. Colorado has a mandatory, payroll tax financed paid sick leave program. Every state has some state and/or local government owned hospitals.
The Obamacare system in place at the federal level is basically a reworking of a Massachusetts state government health care program.
The main reason that this hasn't happened is that the bureaucratic effort it would take to do so would be epic, and it would probably require some level of federal government cooperation, which would be hard to secure at a time when the federal government is gridlocked by a partisan divide between Republicans who control the House of Representatives, Democrats who narrowly control the Senate (but not a filibuster proof level of control) and a Democratic President.
Other countries have universal health care systems primarily set up at a sub-national level, and California could do so too.

How did Massachusetts avoid the trap whereby people move there for cheaper healthcare?  NYC, for example, seems to get gamed quite a bit due to its obligation to shelter the homeless.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The risk turns out to be less than one would guess naively. By far the highest health care costs are seniors who have universal healthcare through Medicare. The poor & disabled have Medicaid. Middle class employees have employer provided healthcare that isn't nearly as visible a cost to them, their employers won't relocate in the short term, and finding a new good job with healthcare is hard. Self-employed would have been much better off, but taxes and a high cost of living cut against that. Universal care mostly helped the working poor with unexpected med expenses.

One remark about sub-national arrangements in other countries:  they may not mean much in practice.  For example, health care is a Canadian provincial responsibility but there are large dollops of Federal funds and every province provides universal health care of some sort.   France theoretically has each of its 95-ish departements looking after own affairs, but in practice its very much a national-run program.  I suspect that Germans do not worry overmuch about differences between Landers either despite them being highly Federal.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica There are details that would have to be worked out so that California wouldn't forgo federal Medicare and Medicaid and VA healthcare money, and Obamacare tax credits. The risk of losing this federal spending is a much bigger problem than the moral hazard of people with high medical costs and low tax spending moving to CA to tip the system out of balance. It could be worked out, but without some arrangement CA would double pay for health care with federal tax dollars it got nothing in return for.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: In Germany, both statutory and private health insurance are mostly regulated by federal law (Sozialgesetzbuch).

@sleske which rather proves my point: regions/provinces in France, Germany and Canada do not operate in the context California would because health care is effectively nationalized.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica One thing to consider is that people with severe, chronic medical issues that may incentivize moving for healthcare are also likely to have difficulty moving.  They'll need to leave their current support structure.  And just because healthcare there would look better on paper doesn't mean it will be better in practice; what if you like your doctor?

What Is It?
How can we say why CA doesn't have "Universal Health Care" if we don't even know what it is? Does this mean single-payer? Private insurance is forbidden? Or it is allowed, but only as a supplement to the UHC? Does it allow balance billing? Does it have pre-authorization? Are there benefit limits? Everyone has a different idea of what UHC is or isn't, which is the biggest obstacle.
Senator Sanders has a simple idea: Medicare for All. Just extend Medicare to the entire US population. That at least makes the definition simple, even if the implementation is still gargantuan. Of course, CA cannot implement Medicare for All because it's a federal program.
A lot of people think that UHC should mean the end of medical bankruptcy in the US. But if balance billing is allowed, then that would not be the case. They think UHC should mean all essential care is covered. But if prior authorization is allowed, citizens would surely get rejected for some procedures, and forced to deal with the private markets. So the first problem is, someone has to define what UHC is and is not. They need a detailed plan. And so far, nobody has put forward a detailed plan for people to even debate or consider, because it's a political football with a high cost of failure.
Lobbying
The biggest cost is not paying for the plan. We already know it is possible to provide high-quality care for fewer dollars than Americans spend today. We already pay more than 2x for the same care in other OECD countries. The biggest cost is dealing with the entrenched stakeholders that will push back on any plan with every resource they can muster, because they will be the biggest losers. Obviously, that includes insurance companies. But it also includes employers, who now enjoy the leverage that comes with holding health insurance policies over employees' heads. And hospital systems, that would surely see lower reimbursement rates (after all, isn't lowering costs one of the major selling points of a UHC???). Even doctors and nurses, who will not come out personally to denounce it, will certainly enlist whatever proxies they can to fight for the status quo, whether that means lobbying from the American Medical Association & friends or siding with insurance and hospital lobbyists. Anyone trying to promote UHC is declaring war on all of these entrenched interests. Clearly, no politician, in CA or elsewhere, feels up to this challenge. Bernie can speak of it openly because he is just one man, tilting at windmills, and everyone knows he is not a serious threat. As soon as a credible threat materializes, that is when the knives will come out and blood will run in the streets.
ObamaCare is far, far short of UHC, but look at how much resistance it faced, not all of it from Republicans. ObamaCare is clearly the most that America as a whole will tolerate when it comes to medical reform, and many pieces in the original proposal were gutted so something could see the light of day (like the single payer option).
America has the greatest health care system in the world...if you're a capitalist. It doesn't matter what the outcomes are, in relative or absolute terms. It generates the most revenue and profit per capita of any health care system, bar none. It stands in a class of its own. And that means that everyone benefiting from this golden goose is highly incentivized to expend a lot of resources to maintain the status quo. California may have a lot of liberals, but perhaps you didn't notice...it has an awful lot of wealthy capitalists, too.

Does "capitalist" = bad? What other system works better?

"Greatest health care system in the world...if you're a capitalist".... providing health services, with pet lobbyists available to talk the government into not negotiating drug costs.  If you're a capitalist in other economic spheres, no, it is still a dog's breakfast.   And if you are looking at the country's overall wealth, it is suboptimal even on capitalist terms.

@DogBoy37 that depends on whether you want to be rich or live forever.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica if you're invested in other sectors, you can still afford to pay for the best care in the world, which also happens to occur in the US for many conditions. And you should have a diverse portfolio, which will almost certainly include some HC stocks. So no, I don't buy the idea that there are rich people in America who do not personally profit from the rampant rent-seeking in the medical sector.

I think your last paragraph would be better if it read: "greatest health care system in the world...if you're profiting from it rather than counting on it to care for your own health".  When it's paid for by employers, the employee/subscriber is not the customer, so the system serves the interest of the employer.

@LawnmowerMan That doesn't make any sense.  If your portfolio has healthcare in it, that doesn't stop the fact that the suck on US productivity impacts the rest of your stocks.  Think of all the glorious extra revenues from oil, tobacco and arms stocks if their performance wasn't dragged down by the darn healthcare suck on the US economy.  Your answer is spot on (+1), in that US healthcare has been captured by vampiric capitalist firms and they will lobby mightily to keep it so, including in California.  But... the wasted GDP chasing iffy health outcomes is still an overall suck on the economy

I would rather the government stay out of the heathcare business. In the US, does anyone thing the VA is the best run healthcare. It is the longest run government run system. Prior to the mid-1990s, before the government got heavy-handed. The healthcare was less costly and better.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica rent-seeking in any form reduces the productivity of other sectors, whether that's real estate, overpriced burgers or whatever. This is unavoidable, and the people succeeding at it will simply claim it is the free market at work. As long as you are getting a slice of the pie via ownership, you should be happy. Or to put it a different way, what is the opportunity cost of reform when incumbents will expend considerable wealth to preserve the status quo? You're just going to incur waste in a different form.

Because they have no money.
I explain. If the country is rich, it does not mean that they can allocate the money and universal healthcare would mean, that more people is going to visit the hospitals as today.
If there is not enough medic, it does not matter, how much do you pay them. By investing more money, making their lifepath more attractive, you increase the chance that smart people choose to become one of them, instead of choosing, for example, a legal or IT career path. On this way you can increase their number - 20 years later. You have no way to make more medic now.
If a poor man visits a hospital with a broken leg or with pneumonia, someone has to handle him and this whole thing has a price. Someone must pay it. You can let the health insurance pay it, but someone has to pay the health insurance. You can let the state pay it, but then you need to collect more taxes or withdraw the money from other sources.
Ultimately, someone has to pay the the invoices. What the state can do, is to let pay others. The state can not create the goods, it only can redistribute them... we create the goods, you and me, and being in the IT does not surely mean that any of us would have a health insurance, even if we are obliged to have it by law.
Ultimately it is a political decision. You could ask a chessmaster, why he did not capture the queen as it had seemed a good move.

The answer does not go into the detail, why are healthcare costs astronomical in the USA without any acceptable reason. I think, fixing this should happen first, universal healthcare after that. Note, the socialist utopia that you just go to the hospital with your headache and will be cared, that is almost unknnown in the whole world. You need to show them some healthcare id or so, and to make it valid, you need to pay to something. In Germany, for example, universal healthcare is solved by that you obliged by law to have a health insurance.

Note, this version is probably the most acceptable to the socialdarwinist far right guys as well. That is because there is a market race among the insurance companies, but there is no continuous problems with the guys with a sudden problem but without healthcare id. My experience of the German solution is that it works, but the healthcare insurance is annoyingly high and clearly not market-based.

This problem looks unsolvable as it stands because it cannot be approached from either side. The medical costs have ballooned because of the hospital/insurance relationship (hospitals raise the prices almost until the point insurance refuses to pay for it). Now that the prices are so high, how can one implement affordable Universal Health Care? They can't. Ok, let's try to decrease costs, but how? When hospital have their own profit model to maximize.

@FailedUnitTest USA is the home of the free market. There are many hospitals and nothing obliges anyone to go in the most costliest ones. Why the market just doesn't work?

@FailedUnitTest There was also that big power outage, about 20 years ago. As far I remember, it happened because there was a complete liberalization of the electric energy market, but there was only a single power electric network in the state, with a narrow bridge between its northern and southern part. Free market had dictated that bulding additional bridges is a good business and many companies should have done that. But it did not happen. Why? Wtf is in the USA?

@GraySheep I'd say you're unfamiliar with the free market. Healthcare is notorious because you don't usually have much choice about what hospital to go to when you have a heart attack, and it's very hard to get a clear calculation of how much it's going to cost even if you were to try and optimize prices ahead of time.

@prosfilaes Okay, it is hard to calculate. Then there is the insurance, that will calculate, and I choose the cheapest. Law should prescribe that any health insurance must pay for similar urgent matters like a hearth attack in any hospital, and also for all hospitals to create realistic invoices to the insurance in similar out-of-market cases.

@GraySheep Likewise, I don't know where you get the idea that building additional bridges would be good business. One of the notorious problems of a free market is that it doesn't tend to build extra capacity; that costs money, and pays nothing on a day to day basis. 2000–2001 California electricity crisis on Wikipedia explains a lot of this, that the partial deregulation made it more profitable for Enron to play games with that bridge to artificially raise prices than make energy (and certainly not to build more bridges.)

@GraySheep ""For every complex problem, there's a solution that is simple, neat, and wrong." Healthcare is a vastly complex system, and well-meaning laws have increased that complexity and had serious perverse negative effects on it. Saying "law should prescribe" is easy; putting that in explicit legal form and figuring out how that will affect the whole system is hard.

@prosfilaes Problem is that markets have an important but very unsaid feature. That is that humans decide, what is the best for them. Not markets, not companies, not robots, but humans, like you and me, or at least humans are at the end of the command chain. Human existence can not be ever object of market decisions, it can be only subject of it. That has the consequence that in life & death matters, something must exist to preserve the life of the poor humans, even if they have no money. Insurance helps a lot to weaken the problem, because letting many people to pay a little is much

@prosfilaes better as letting some of them to die. Yes, it violates the free market principes, and what's then? I am more happy by paying a little to the obligatory insurance, knowing that I won't die if I get a hearth attack on the street and I do not have my insurance card in my pockets. If the system is s..t, then I vote differently or go to another state.
